# Mask the server name in the url in IIS 7

Tags: url, masking

I created a new mvc application, published it and deployed it on the sever under the default websites in IIS 7. Now I can access the website from my local system using the url http://server1/mymvcapp/login

Server1 is the server name where the application is deployed.

How can I mask the server name "server1" in the url to a more user friendly name, for example http://hellomvc.com/mymvcapp/login

Answer (score 0):

You need setup  DNS server or user hosted DNS (it's optional). You can read more here:

[setup-a-website-with-dns-and-iis-7](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8529cb50-4433-4f8b-82e5-ae067044d877/setup-a-website-with-dns-and-iis-7?forum=winserverNIS)

and here:
[installing-windows-dns-server](http://www.iisunderground.com/installing-windows-dns-server/)

Usualy for host nameservers of domain  name you need 2 external IP addresses.